# matlab reading variables from config text file

Tags: matlab, configuration

Assuming that I have a file called **config.txt**
with the following content

```
var1="value1"
var2="value2"
....
....
var100="value100"
```

I want to read it in matlab as a variable called config such that I can access all sub-variables directly from it

```
input:
config.var1 
output:
'value1'
```

Thanks

Comment: Are `value1`, `value2` etc really strings?

Comment: @SardarUsama Not always. Sometimes are nummeric

Comment: If instead you stored it as `config.m`, you could just call `run` and run it as a script. You would need to use `config.var1` instead of just `var1` in your `.m` file.

Comment: if  the data type is same, the solution would be fairly simple. but differentiating between the datatypes, well,......

Comment: @SardarUsama Assuming the the data type is same, what would is the recommended solution.

Comment: That's really too much to assume if it is not. In case it is same you could use `textscan` with related typespecifier. I suggest you to create an example of exactly what data you have instead of "value1" etc. Something that clearly explains what you're dealing with